# How to inflate a activity in my case?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I would like to achieve this layout :

my main activity layout (**main.xml**);

(**Please mouse right click the following image and view image**)

[image]

I have made another **ContentActivity** (with content set to **content_one.xml**) which is supposed to be used as part (the right part) of the above layout:

[image]

I know I can inflate a layout by:

```
LinearLayout mainLayout =  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)Home2.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View inflatedView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_one, null);

mainLayout.addView(inflatedView);
```

I am wondering, besides inflate the content_one layout into main layout, **is it possible to inflate a activity class instead of inflating a layout** in android? If possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant inflate an Activity as such. Consider using Fragments.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Comment: @ kumar Bibek , is fragment only supported by android 3.0 ? If I am using android 2.1 updated, can I use fragment?

Comment: Yes you can, by using the Fragments static library. http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html