# about working with Fragment in Android 2.1 updated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

My first question I'd like to ask is that is it so that **Fragment** is only supported by **android 3.0** ? If I am developing **Android 2.1** application, can I use **Fragment**?

My second question is, I am implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675747/how-to-inflate-a-activity-in-my-case) simple feature, **Fragment** is a good choice, but I am developing **Android 2.1** application, if the answer of my first question is negative, what could be the workaround to implement the feature I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use Fragment with Android 1.6 and later. See this post on the Android blog: [Fragments For All](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html)

Comment: @ xevincent , after I install the component through Eclipse "Android SDK and AVD manager" do I need to do something else or I can already use the Fragment directly? in @ AshtonBRSC suggested link, seems I have to create a lib directory and configure something (See "Setting Up a Project to Use the Library") http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Comment: Follow the steps in http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html. You have to include the jar in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Fragments Compatability Library that works with Android 1.6 and above:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html